# Angular2 functions in template and change detection

Tags: function, angular, templates

Im trying to build a method inside a service that checks whether a navigation button should be showed to the current user based on his permissions or not (this is just cosmetic "security" I know). Therefore this is the button placed inside the template

```
<button [routerLink]="['/some/where']"
        *ngIf="AuthService.isAuthorized(['some', 'where'])">
    Personen
</button>
```

The method `AuthService.isAuthorized` uses the provided array to run through all available routes and get the required permissions from the particular route's data object:

```
{
    path: 'some',
    component: SomeComponent,
    data: {
        permissions: [
            "read:some",
            "edit:some"
        ]
    },
    children: [
        {
            path: 'where',
            component: SomeComponent,
            data: {
                permissions: [
                    "read:where"
                ]
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

so in this case the permissions `["read:some","edit:some","read:where"]` are needed by the current signed in user so that the button would be displayed to him. **Working so far!**

But since the function is called inside the template it is called multiple times because of angular change detection. How could I change my code so that the function is called only once? Even better if it would only be called once **after** the authentication finished writing all permissions assigned to the authenticated user into AuthService.permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make AuthService.isAuthorized() method returns a promise:

```
@injectable()
export class AuthService {
  ...
  isAuthorized(arr: string[]): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise(resolve =>{
      // your logic here
      resolve(yourResult);
    });
  }
  ...
}
```

You can call this method on your `ngOnInit` of a component (Therefore it will be called once). You pass the return value to a new variable (e.g. `isAuthorized`) in the component and use this variable in the template instead.

```
@Component({
selector: "your-component",
templateUrl: "yourTemplate.html"
})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
  isAuthorized: boolean;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.isAuthorized(['some', 'where']).then(result => {
      this.isAuthorized = result;
    });
  }
}
```

In the template you can just use `isAuthorized` variable.

```
<button [routerLink]="['/some/where']"
    *ngIf="isAuthorized">
Personen
</button>
```

**Edit:**
If AuthService.isAuthorized() needed to be called only once but for more than one element, code like these may suits your need:

```
@Component({
selector: "your-component",
templateUrl: "yourTemplate.html"
})
export class YourComponent {
  isObjectAuthorized = {} as {
    isFirstAuthorized: boolean;
    isSecondAuthorized: boolean;
  };  

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  checkForAuthorization(isElementAuthorized, arr: string[]) {
    if (isElementAuthorized !== undefined) {
      return;
    }

    this.authService.isAuthorized(arr).then(result => {
      isElementAuthorized = result;
    });
  }
}
```

And in your template:

```
<button [routerLink]="['/some/where']"
    *ngIf="checkForAuthorization(isObjectAuthorized.isFirstAuthorized, ['some', 'where'])">
First
</button>
<button [routerLink]="['/some/where']"
    *ngIf="checkForAuthorization(isObjectAuthorized.isSecondAuthorized, ['some', 'where', 'else'])">
Second
</button>
```

Comment: So this helps running the function only once. The thing is the function should be used on not only one but certain different elements.
`<button [routerLink]="['/some/where']" *ngIf="auh.isAuthorized(['some', 'where'])">First</button><button [routerLink]="['/some/where/else']" *ngIf="auh.isAuthorized(['some', 'where', 'else'])">Second</button>`. @samAlvin Your solution would need me to call the function for every element I want to use it on inside the ngOnInit method and creating a isAuthorizedElementName property for each element inside the component as well.

Comment: @MaxSolid I've edited my answer, added solution for different elements