# Angular ngIf and ngFor with function gets called many times per second

Tags: angular

I noticed using ngIf or ngFor with a function will call the function many times per second. In contrast using a string, number or object it will be checked only when change detection kicks in.

Am i doing something wrong? Or is this the expected behavior? I would say there is no need to check the function again if nothing changed somewhere.

Example:

Component:

```
myFunction() {
    console.log('I was checked');
    return true;
}
```

Template:

```
<div *ngIf="myFunction()">hello there!</div>
```

Comment: This looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35469024/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-work or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42661353/angular2-functions-in-template-and-change-detection

Comment: Yes it's expected: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43085186/6294072

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior.

Angular performs a lot of checks per millisecond to detect whether something changed or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ChangeDetectionStrategy` to avoid this. I am no so sure of this.

```
@Component({
  // ...
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class MyComponent {
  // ...
}
```